# How to reference a String variable in a class

Tags: swift

I know that in Swift a String has a "by value" concept. Nevertheless, I have a use case where I need to reference a String living outside a class. How can I achieve this in Swift (read-only access in the class would already be sufficient)?

This should be enough of information as it says everything needed and I basically would like to know about how to solve this in Swift as in most other languages you have references. The current use case though is as following:

I have a SwiftUI controls which are bound to String variables. Then I have a generic validation class which has an array of references to those string variables. The validation class should then be able to check all those text strings.

Comment: What do you have to store in this string?

Comment: @Mat: That string holds the text for a SwiftUI text control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be not the best solution, but you can achieve this with `Pointers`, like so:

```swift
class Test {
    
    private let strPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<String>
    
    init(strPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<String>) {
        self.strPointer = strPointer
    }
    
    func doStuff() {
        print(strPointer.pointee)
    }
    
}

var str = "Initial value"

let test = Test(strPointer: &str)
test.doStuff()
// prints 'Initial value'

str = "Another value"
test.doStuff()
// prints 'Another value'
```

Comment: @Codo, can you pls explain me why? Pointer stores a reference to a memory cell, and if we change the value stored itself, the reference won't change, and we'll get the recent value, as it is shown in the sample above. When we might loose access to the newest value?

Comment: If you change the value of a string, is it really always stored at the same place in memory as the old one? Doesn't get the string with the old value destroyed and a new string is created with the new value?

Comment: @G.Marc, Just try a code snippet above. Pointer will be valid and will be pointing to the recent value of the variable as long as the context, in which variable is presented, (so the variable itself) exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think the task is a bit inadequate, since `String` instances in Swift are not reference objects. It's not "by concept", it's implementational.

However, you say that "a read-only access would be sufficient", so, if you only read the string and never assign it or modify, you can be sure that you always read exactly the object you're accessing, right?

```swift
struct SomeType {
  let someString: String
}

let someType = SomeType(someString: "Some string")

/*
Is it possible that directly accessing a property would give you some
other object? I don't think so.
*/
someType.someString
```

If you need to assign a string to a variable and to make sure that it points to the same object in memory, you need a reference type. For instance, if you have access to the Foundation library, you can use good ol' `NSString`:

```swift
import Foundation

struct SomeType {
  let someString: NSString
}

let someString: NSString = "Some string"
let someType = SomeType(someString: someString)

let someStringRef = someType.someString

print(ObjectIdentifier(someString)) // 0xdfe57cb5a0a52888
print(ObjectIdentifier(someType.someString)) // 0xdfe57cb5a0a52888
print(ObjectIdentifier(someStringRef)) // 0xdfe57cb5a0a52888

print(someString === someType.someString) // true
print(someStringRef === someType.someString) // true
```